# Rooms to let in Greece during beginning of July

Tags: accommodation, greece

I used to go to Greece quite some times, mostly in July. We always went for rooms to let, which were cheap, but most of all, was nice to stay with inhabitants instead of (too) commercial hotels.

I wonder if this is still possible in July./ high season.

Addition: we don't want to book in advance.

Comment: Any specific destination you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, Crete, probably some other islands like Kos.

Comment: Crete is a great place indeed and for sure you will find rooms to let with no need of book in advance. http://www.agia-galini.com/en/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely possible to find rooms to let, even in high season with no need to book in advance. It may be more difficult to find decent rooms during weekends, when locals are trying to escape and have their own holidays too (since the imposed "financial crisis", most of the people now either cannot have any holidays or stay in Greece).

Having lived in Crete for a few years, my two cents:

- http://www.monachus-monachus.gr/
- http://www.sougialotos.gr/

The smallest the island obviously the more difficult to find accommodation, so for Kos it might be wiser to book in advance for peace of mind.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to find it is to check it at "Room to let" sites, like [Roomorama](https://roomorama.com/short-term-rentals?utf8=%E2%9C%93&destination=greece&check_in=&check_out=&guests=1) or [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com.sg/s?location=greece&checkin=&checkout=&guests=1).

The room will definitely available in July as long as you book it as early as possible.

Comment: We don't like to book in advance, forgot to mention that in my question above. However, those prices in that site are not really cheap.